# How to execute a default method before the interface implementation code C#?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, domain-driven-design, solid-principles

I have an interface which implements only one method:

```
public interface IHandler<T> where T : Comand
{
    Task<IResultComand> HandlerAsync(T comand);
}
```

And I use it in my classes as follows:

```
public class ProductHandler : IHandler<NewProductComand>,
                              IHandler<EditProductComand>,
                              IHandler<DeleteProductComand>

public async Task<IResultComand> HandlerAsync(NewProductComand comand) 
{
        ResultComand result = new();

        comand.Validate();
        if (!comand.Valid)
        {
            return result;
        }

        //Create new product

        return result;
}

public async Task<IResultComand> HandlerAsync(EditProductComand comand) 
{
        ResultComand result = new();

        comand.Validate();
        if (!comand.Valid)
        {
            return result;
        }

        //Edit product

        return result;
}

public async Task<IResultComand> HandlerAsync(DeleteProductComand comand) 
{
        ResultComand result = new();

        comand.Validate();
        if (!comand.Valid)
        {
            return result;
        }

        //Delete product

        return result;
}
```

And my `Comand` has the following code:

```
 public abstract class Comand
 {
    public bool Valid { get; set; }

    public abstract void Validate();
 }
```

How to make the following code run implicitly before executing the implementation code in `HandlerAsync`? (Some thing like a [ActionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0) Web API .NET)

```
    ResultComand result = new();

    comand.Validate();
    if (!comand.Valid)
    {
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "run implictely". From the code above I suppose you just want to avoid repeading the code for all the three methods. In order to achieve that you may just provide a private method `async Task<IResultComand> HandlerAsync(Command comand) ` with the common code and call that one from all the three methods.

Comment: Additionally as you mention ActionFilters(s). They are not called implicitly. Asp.Net has pretty complex code todo it pretty explicitly. You just don't see it because its Framework stuff. You might do something like it here. But be aware that creating such a framework is way more complicated then just a simple refactoring as @MakePeaceGreatAgain suggests.

Comment: Because the refactoring doesn't solve the code line number much in this case. Because the code should only return if the `Comand` is invalid, otherwise it should continue executing. Thank you guys @MakePeaceGreatAgain @Ralf

Comment: Maybe what I need is [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the Decorator Pattern.

Basically, you leave your 'base' CommandHandler as it is and let it do its job, but you add an additional class that implements the same interface:

```
ExtraStuffCommandHandlerDecorator<TComand> : IHandler<TComand>
    where TComand : Comand
{
    readonly IHandler<TComand> _decorated;

    public ExtraStuffCommandHandlerDecorator(IHandler<TComand> decorated)
    {
        _decorated = decorated;
    }

    public async Task<IResultComand> HandlerAsync(TComand comand)
    {
        // Do stuff before base command execution

        IResultComand result = await _decorated.HandlerAsync(comand);

        // Do stuff after base command execution

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now your mediator that is currently instantiating and calling the base handler directly, should instead look up the decorator and call that instead, passing the base handler in as a constructor argument.

Using decorators is well supported by Autofac's RegisterGenericDecorator method.  Implementation with Asp Core DI is a little more complex, but here's a guide.

https://andrewlock.net/adding-decorated-classes-to-the-asp.net-core-di-container-using-scrutor/#manually-creating-decorators-with-the-asp-net-core-di-container

Comment: Thanks for sharing Decorator Pattern